# How to recieve a Byte array using JACOB?

Tags: java, com, variant, jacob

I am writing a software in java and using [JACOB](https://github.com/freemansoft/jacob-project) to invoke methods of a library of type .dll, I am also using [Variant](https://github.com/freemansoft/jacob-project/blob/f20f5c46f992ad7e19a5864dc320fcdac913a998/src/com/jacob/com/Variant.java#L41) to send the input parameters and receive the return values. One of the functions have a return value of byte array. How to use [Variant](https://github.com/freemansoft/jacob-project/blob/f20f5c46f992ad7e19a5864dc320fcdac913a998/src/com/jacob/com/Variant.java#L41) to get this array and iterate on it?

Comment: It ultimately depends on how the library is exactly designed, as there are many ways to pass VARIANT arguments. Usually a byte array is a SAFEARRAY of type VT_UI1, so the VARTYPE is VT_UI1 | VT_ARRAY and it contains the safearray (pointer). Not sure how you do this with this Jacob library.

Comment: @SimonMourier  Could you recommend other libraries that can accomplish this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I don't know much about JAVA, I know only the COM side.

Comment: You call `Variant.toSafeArray()` and then use the methods of `SafeArray` to get the byte array.